# Are Tools related questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are Tools related questions off topic?
I think there are varying levels of tool questions and some will be suitable and some won't be.
The original question I was going to ask, but thought twice about was:

> What size air compressor (HP, Tank
>   Size, CFM, etc) would be suitable for
>   a home garage where I'm going to do
>   small amounts of maintenance but
>   nothing major? i.e. I would need to be
>   able to use a tyre inflator and a
>   rattle gun, I'd like to be able to do
>   small amounts of spray painting but I
>   don't plan to respray an entire car.

It's not directly related to Maintenance and Repair and isn't directly related to a maintenance/repair question, it could be a little subjective so I was unsure.
Compared with a question like:

> What tools will I require to change
>   the front pads and bleed the brakes on
>   a 1977 XC Ford Falcon?

(which I personally think is on topic, but I don't know for sure)

Is there guidance on this somewhere that I haven't come across?
Any Thoughts?

Comment: Agree with Jeff, post the question about the compressor, there are several things that go into the decision on what to buy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So long as the tools questions are in the context of *motor vehicles* -- either specifically for working on motor vehicles, or for some specific repair situation involving a motor vehicle -- I personally think it's OK.

If it degenerates into general tools questions with no specific tie to repairing a car, motorcycle, or truck .. that'd be less acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Both of those questions are on-topic and answerable.  For example, your first question doesn't sound like a compressor that's going to drive serious air-tools.  The second one is also answerable with a straight list of parts.